# How do I use fgets or getline if I don't have a stream but a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, posix, gnu

How do I use fgets or getline if I don't have a stream but a file descriptor  ?

According to manpage of [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> It is not advisable to mix calls to input functions from the stdio
> library with low-level calls to read(2) for the file descriptor
> associated with the input stream; the results will be undefined and
> very probably not what you want.

Comment: [fdopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use read() function to read from file descriptor and it's very clear, from man page:

> read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count); read() attempts to read up to
> count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.